# Prove one city is connected to another

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

> Given several cities in a country. City X is directly connected to 23 other cities. City Y is directly connected to 3 other cities. Each city, except X and Y, is directly connected to 10 other cities. Prove that there is an route (maybe with city changes) between X and Y.

I used handshaking lemma in this case and got the number of edges according to the constraints which can then be compared with the minimum number of edges needed in graph so that it is connected.

Here the number of vertices can be at the most 28 according to the constraints.

Is there a better approach to prove the same?

Comment: Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are disconnected. Consider the connected components containing $X$ and $Y$ and use the handshaking lemma to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: @player3236 Thank you had a query in this case should i negate this statement every city is not connected to 10 other cities as an assumption for contradiction?

Comment: No, you need only negate the conclusion for a proof by contradiction. In fact you will need to use the 10-cities-connection.

Comment: @player3236 thanks then here i have to assume that there is no route between X and Y and then negate this by proof of contradiction?

Comment: Kinda. It should go as: "No route => (magic) => contradiction. Hence $\exists$ route".

Comment: @player3236 thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather simple problem if you do this trick:

> Observe that any graph can be separated in some disjoint connected graphs.

---

Suppose our graph is $G$. We assume there is no path between $X$ and $Y$. Thus, $G$ is not connected.

Let us split $G$ into $G_1$, $G_2$,...,$G_k$, all disjoint and connected. There is no edge between $X$ and $Y$ means that $X$ and $Y$ are not in the same $G_i$.

Let $n$ such that $X\in G_n$. Then, suppose we have $x$ other cities, which are different from $Y$, so they all have a degree of $10$. The degree of $X$ is $23$, so $$\sum_{v\in G_n}deg(v)$$

is odd, which is a contradiction, because in any graph $$\sum_{v\in G}deg(v)=2e$$

where $e$ is the number of edges.

So there must be a path between $X$ and $Y$

---

Note: this problem can be generalized in many ways. The only important values here are the parity of degrees. Good luck!

Comment: Got it thank you

Comment: I am glad to hear!